# click on background layout when dialog is already opened

Tags: android, google-maps, view, dialog, google-maps-markers

I have developed app which i have integrated [Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/). Now i set so many pins on the google map. When i click on any pin then that pin `marker` detail will be displayed in one dialog. This all are working perfectly.This is the [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eqRV.png) .
**Problem is:-** when i click one any marker then dialog is opened but when i click on second marker then first dismiss was dismiss. After again click on that marker dialog will be open, but i want to open new dialog when click one any `marker`. Is this possible that whenever i click on any marker(look at the image) then that marker related(means data) dialog will open instantly ?

I tried with this `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`, but it is just dismiss the dialog when i click on out side the dialog layout.

Thanks in advance and help would be very appreciate.

This is the dialog method where i can open the dialog

```
Dialog mapMarkerDialog = null;
private void showMapMarkerDialog(Marker marker)
    {
        try
        {
            mapMarkerDialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
            mapMarkerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map_info_window);
            mapMarkerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            RelativeLayout llMapClubDetailTop = (RelativeLayout)mapMarkerDialog.findViewById(R.id.llMapClubDetailTop);
            LinearLayout llMapClubDetail = (LinearLayout)mapMarkerDialog.findViewById(R.id.llMapClubDetail);

            ImageView imgMapDialogClubImage = (ImageView)mapMarkerDialog.findViewById(R.id.imgMapDialogClubImage);
            TextView txtMapDialogClubName = (TextView)mapMarkerDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMapDialogClubName);
            TextView txtMapDialogClubLocation = (TextView)mapMarkerDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMapDialogClubLocation);
            TextView txtMapDialogClubDiscount = (TextView)mapMarkerDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMapDialogClubDiscount);


            llMapClubDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mapMarkerDialog.dismiss();
                    mapMarkerDialog.cancel();
                    //start new activity
                }
            });


            mapMarkerDialog.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "***Error while call showMapMarkerDialog() method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of dialog use ViewGroup to show this informations. You can show and hide the ViewGroup using visibility property.

Comment: @SureshKumar thank for your reply but can you give some more information about `ViewGroup`?

Comment: use `popup window` instead of dialog.

Comment: i have check this but i don't get exact idea https://android--code.blogspot.in/2016/01/android-popup-window-example.html

Answer (score 1):

when you are using dialog then `View` is added on your main layout so you can not click on background. You must have to delete the `View` (dialog) before open new view. When you need to do like this type of functionality then I suggest you that use [Popup Window](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) so you can display an arbitrary view.

Please try this below code. This is for just show popup window only you can use as per your requirement.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popuplayoutReject = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);

final PopupWindow popUpReject = new PopupWindow(popuplayoutReject, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);

popUpReject.setOutsideTouchable(true);

popUpReject.showAtLocation(popuplayoutReject, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Its works Charms. Can you please give some more about this?